# Can I make a cell separated diagonally in a table

Tags: pages, text-editor

I'm using Pages for a document where I need to have a table that has both rows and column headings. (I have no idea how such tables are called.)

This is what I have now:
[image]

The following screenshot pictures what I'm after:
[image]